# How to query data-attribute for a whitespace-separated value in Cypress component tests?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, custom-data-attribute

When testing a complex component, I want to assign multiple whitespace-separated values to `data-cy` attribute, for example

```html
<div data-cy="my-component disabled" />
```

and use the `~=` attribute selector to query for the element:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy~="my-component"]')
```

Now, having already queried for `my-component`, how can I further assert that it:

- does contain "disabled" in `data-cy`
- does not contain "disabled" in `data-cy`
- in broader sense, does or does not satisfy a css selector?

---

I know I can explicitly re-query with all parameters for each assertion, eg.:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy~="my-component"]:not([data-cy~="disabled"])').should('exist')
```

but this feels overly complicated and doesn't read very well - I want to query the element first, and further assert against it in a later step - for example:

```js
cy.get('...').should(el => { 
   // assert here
})
```

Comment: Why would `disabled` not just be an attribute on the element? `<div data-cy="my component" disabled>`? `data-cy` is usually used in a manner similar to `id` or `name`, so treating `data-cy` more similar to `class` seems weird to me.

Comment: You may be right, maybe adding a separate a data attribute for each functionality is a more reasonable approach. My sole motivation was encapsulating all test-related data inside a single attribute, so it doesn't polute the DOM and the data has an explicitly stated purpose - but maybe I'm not aiming at the right targets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Chai-jQuery assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Chai-jQuery) `expect($el).match(selector)` does exactly that!

```js
// should form
cy.get('[data-cy~="my-component"]')
  .should('match', '[data-cy~="some-value"]')  
  .should('match', ':not([data-cy~="something-else"])')

// expect form
cy.get('[data-cy~="my-component"]')
  .then(el => expect(el).to.match('[data-cy~="some-value"]'))
  .then(el => expect(el).to.match(':not([data-cy~="something-else"])'))
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom command for that? `cy.get('[data-cy~="my-component"]')
  .should('match', '[data-cy~="something-else"]')`

Comment: You are right, I don't need it! I didn't know I can use this assertion in `should`, too! I corrected my answer.

Comment: `.should()` is kind of syntactic sugar, anything `expect(actualValue)...` can be used with it and `actualValue` is passed along from previous command.

Comment: The bonus with `.should()` is it will retry if initially fails. In your "expect form" section, change `.then()` to `.should()` to make it retry-able.

Comment: I believe that my "expect form" is retry-able too, since it's chained after `cy.get()`

Comment: No it's not, there's a note somewhere in the docs about it.

Comment: Of course, `data-cy` is a static attribute (you add it in source and it's there on the page on load). But if you test with `disabled` for example, adding it after 1000ms you will find your code above is failing.

Answer (score 1):

The approach seems like a good one. If you used individual attributes, likely they would clash with other "native" attributes.

For example if `data-cy="disabled"` means the "Person" has a disability, but used unwrapped the browser would disable the element.

Ref [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

> data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on DOM.

Also some frameworks (React) are fussy about the attributes allowed on an element.

---

You might be looking for a function to provide the selector for the test.

```js
const asDataCy = (attrs) => {
  return attrs.split(' ').map(attr => {
    let op = '~'
    if (item.charAt(0) === '!') {
      op = '!'
      attr = attr.slice(1)
    }
    return `[data-cy${op}="${attr}"]`
  ).join('')
}

cy.get(asDataCy('my-component !disabled'))  
        // [data-cy~="my-component"][data-cy!="disabled"])
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems potentially useful, but it doesn't allow me to test against already queried elements. I would love to find a way to do that.

Comment: What would be an example? I expect it to work anywhere a selector is used.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it should work everywhere, I just don't like the approach very much. I tried to describe this in the question, but maybe have not done a good job... The way I want this to work is "First query for `my-component`. Now, assert if it has such and such attributes (possibly even by one)" as opposed to "Try to find  `my-component` with this exact combination of attributes, and assert if it exists". I find the first flow much clearer and more desirable.

Comment: Well, yes that's a different question. Cypress already has the "flow" pattern you like, if you want to eliminate the `[data-cy...]` baggage you can wrap it in a `cy.dataCy(attribute)` custom command. It's not really a technical problem, more one of décor.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am trying to say - at least I'm unable to make any sense of your answer in my context. I want to FIRST get the element regardless of what other attributes it has and THEN try to match queries (possibly one by one) in another step (for example chained fn calls). Your suggested solution does not do that - it queries against a single combination of attributes at once in a single step, and then asserts whether it found an element. So my question is HOW can I achieve the logical flow I am looking for - I see nothing in your comment that points me to that.

Comment: That is totally different to what you asked for in the question, and show in the example. And there is little difference in the outcome between querying sequentially vs querying in one selector.

Comment: @user16695029 Thank you for your feedback, I have edited the question to make it clearer